# split dataframe by vector in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with 500 columns and x rows. Now i have a vector `t_1` and a vector `t_2`. Vector `t_1` means the start of an event and can contain 1 or more values and `t_2` is the end of an event. Both of them indicate the location of a row in the dataframe.

example:

```
 t1=[4202 6453]
 t2=[6203 6492]
```

I want to split the dataframe now into to parts and save it as two different dataframes. Row 4202 to 6203 is dataframe1 and row 6453 to 6492 is dataframe 2.
This would be the whole Dataframe:

```
      A   B   C   D
1     5   2   3   4 
..    .   .   .   .
4202  3   4   2   1
4203  2   1   2   2
..    .   .   .   .
6203  1   2   3   1
..    .   .   .   .
6453  5   1   4   3
..    .   .   .   .
6492  1   2   3   4
```

and this should be the output:
Dataframe 1:

```
      A   B   C   D
4202  3   4   2   1
..    .   .   .   .
6203  1   2   3   1
```

and Dataframe 2:

```
      A   B   C   D
6453  5   1   4   3
..    .   .   .   .
6492  1   2   3   4
```

Thank you,
R

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need `list comprehension` with `loc` and `zip` for list of `DataFrame`s:

```
t1=[4202, 6453]
t2=[6203, 6492]

dfs = [df.loc[i:j] for i, j in zip(t1, t2)]

print (dfs[0])
print (dfs[1])
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(142)

df = pd.DataFrame({'column':np.random.rand(8)})
print (df)
     column
0  0.902062
1  0.557808
2  0.655985
3  0.832471
4  0.199884
5  0.127254
6  0.771439
7  0.432289
```

---

```
t1=[1, 3]
t2=[2, 5]

dfs = [df.loc[i:j] for i, j in zip(t1, t2)]
print (dfs)
[     column
1  0.557808
2  0.655985,      column
3  0.832471
4  0.199884
5  0.127254]

print (dfs[0])
     column
1  0.557808
2  0.655985

print (dfs[1])
     column
3  0.832471
4  0.199884
5  0.127254
```

Comment: Both of my vectors  indicate the location of a row in the dataframe. do you still think this would work?

Comment: @raffa_sa - Not understand, can you add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: but I want to have the dataframe between the first value of t1 and the first value of t2-> 4202 - 6203 and then the second dataframe between the second value of t1 and t2 -> 6453 - 6492

Comment: @raffa_sa - oops, sorry. Edited again.

Comment: it worked, but now i have a list cotaining these parts. do you have an idea how to save it now to df1 and df2 in a pd dataframe?

Comment: Use `df1, df2 = [df.loc[i:j] for i, j in zip(t1, t2)]`

Comment: @raffa_sa - Or `df1 = dfs[0]`, `df2 = dfs[1]`

Comment: the difficult thing is I don't know at the beginning if t1 contains 1 two or three values. if t1 and t2 are containing one value -> one dataframe. 2 values in t1 and t2 -> two dataframes. 3 values in t1 and t2 -> 3 dataframes. If i write df, df2 = ... this only works for 2 values. Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: @raffa_sa - yes, and it is reason for list of DataFrames.

Comment: @raffa_sa - not sure how is define `t1`, `t2` ? Because number of splited DataFrames depends of length of `t1, t2`.

Comment: Store as a dictionary, keyed on the enumerated zip values?